# Measure NVIDIA Tensor Cores speedup

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm using NVIDIA Tensor Cores on Volta architecture (V100 GPU). I want to measure impact of Tensor Cores on my code, (a Convolutional Neural Network in Tensorflow/Python for testing purpose).

How can I measure Tensor Cores speedup ? Is it possible to disable Tensor Cores and run the same code with/without them ?

What I've tried:

- setting  `TF_DISABLE_CUDNN_TENSOR_OP_MATH` to 1 (from [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dgx/tensorflow-user-guide/index.html#tf_disable_tensor_op_math)). But I still see that Tensor Cores are used. More precisely, I see in `nvprof` log: `volta_s884cudnn_fp16` lines (disappear with this option) and `volta_s884gemm_fp16` (which are still here). Side question: what do these lines mean ?
- compare with same code on Pascal architecture (P100) which has no Tensor Cores, where I see a 30% speedup, but I can't tell which part of this 30% is caused by GPU improvement and which part is Tensor Cores performance.
- training same network in `tf.float16` and `tf.float32`, but same result, I see improvements but can't tell what is caused by model size reduction.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice on this.

Comment: My guess is that volta_s884gemm_fp16 comes from cuBLAS library, some ops call cuBLAS directly, and therefore the call is not affected by the TF_DISABLE_CUDNN_TENSOR_OP_MATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose a hack to estimate the performance gain of Tensor Cores:

- I ran the code in `float32` on both Pascal and Volta architecture (to estimate the performance gain of the architecture).
- I ran the code in `float16` on both too, and assuming the performance gain of the architecture would be the same with `float32` and `float16`, I can estimate that the other part of the performance gain (in `float16`) is imputable to Tensor Cores.